# Changing the time on a batch of images using Python

Tags: image, date, exif

Is there a way to change the timestamp on a batch of images? When my wife and I went on vacation, she forgot to set the time to the local time, so now all of her timestamps are off by 5 hours, which makes figuring out where they were taken more challenging.

I came across a module named Pillow that "might" work, but throwing this out there for anything suggestions on how this can be done in Python (I'm just learning Python myself, so the easier the solution, the better).

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: It's a one-liner, with no Python necessary using `jhead` or `exiftool` see here... https://petapixel.com/2012/11/05/how-to-fix-your-timestamps-if-you-forgot-to-update-your-camera-for-daylight-savings/  Try it in a separate directory on a **copy** of 2-3 files first - it is a very powerful tool that can change a lot of things very fast!

Comment: Thanks for those tools. After a quick glance, exiftool looks like the most user-friendly one of the two. I'll give it a try today.

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: No probs, good luck!